# KMM. Can't run app in IOS simulator. App uses cocoapods dependency

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I added Twilio Conversations dependency like below:

```
cocoapods {
    version = "1.0"
    summary = "Some description for a Kotlin/Native module"
    homepage = "https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin"

    ios.deploymentTarget = "15.2"

    specRepos {
        url("https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs")
    }
    pod("TwilioConversationsClient") {
        version = "~> 4.0"
    }
}
```

And, as it stated in the documentation. I am able to use it in Kotlin code:

```
import cocoapods.TwilioConversationsClient.TCHConversation
import kotlinx.cinterop.ExperimentalForeignApi

@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
actual suspend fun getConversations(): List<String> {
    return listOf(
        TCHConversation.toString()
    )
}
```

However when I am running the app in IOS Simulator I am getting the following error in Android Studio:

```
Ld /Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/KotlinProject.app/KotlinProject normal (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')
    cd /Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/iosApp
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -Xlinker -reproducible -target arm64-apple-ios15.2-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.0.sdk -O0 -L/Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/build/ios/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/build/ios/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/iosApp/../shared/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator17.0 -F/Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/iosApp/../composeApp/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator17.0 -filelist /Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/KotlinProject.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/KotlinProject_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/KotlinProject.swiftmodule -Objc -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/KotlinProject.app-Simulated.xcent -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __ents_der -Xlinker /Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/KotlinProject.app-Simulated.xcent.der -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/KotlinProject_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/KotlinProject.app/KotlinProject
ld: warning: search path '/Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/iosApp/../shared/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator17.0' not found
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'TwilioConversationsClient': framework 'TwilioConversationsClient' not found
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_TCHConversation, referenced from:
       in ComposeApp[arm64][2](ComposeApp.framework.o)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/xudoyshukur/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProjectKMP/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/KotlinProject.app/KotlinProject normal (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')
(1 failure)
```

[image]

Comment: Tried:
* Adding '-ObjC' linker flag in AS and Xcode
* Changing run destination to Rosetta
* Cleaning and rebuilding (too many times)

Comment: If I remove TCHConversation.toString() line, the app runs normally.

Comment: @Vega What do you mean?

Comment: @Vega I still do not understand what you mean.
However I changed images to text. If you are familiar with Kotlin Multiplatform you should understand what the code means. Additionally I provided comments on top of the images.

Comment: @Vega added error text